# Title truncation in JPanel TitledBorder - Java swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, truncation, titled-border

I've got a JPanel with a TitledBorder, but the contents of the panel are narrower than the title in the border and the title gets truncated.
I am using BoxLayout for the JPanel which as depicted [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) pays attention to manual setting of width. I tried to set the minimum, maximum and preferred width of the panel according to the TitledBorder getMinimumSize() function along with the width of its components but all don't work. The only thing that worked was using a box filler but that introduced an undesired indentation.

Any way to the show the full title irrespective to the content it contains?

```
this.jpCases.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(this.jpCases, javax.swing.BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        List<Category> categories = db.getCategories();
        for (Category cat : categories) {
            JPanel jp = new JPanel();
            TitledBorder tb = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(cat.getDescription());

            jp.setBorder(tb);
            jp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            jp.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
            jp.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

            List<Case> cases = db.getCasesByCategoryId(cat.getId());
            for (Case c : cases) {
                JRadioButton jrbCase = new JRadioButton();
                jrbCase.setText(c.getDescription());
                jrbCase.setToolTipText(c.getText());
                jrbCase.setMaximumSize(tb.getMinimumSize(jp));
                bgCases.add(jrbCase);
                jp.add(jrbCase);
            }
        //jp.add(new Box.Filler(tb.getMinimumSize(jp), tb.getMinimumSize(jp), tb.getMinimumSize(jp)));
            this.jpCases.add(jp);
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about calculating the needed width:

```
       JRadioButton jrb = new JRadioButton();
       int width = (int) SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics( jrb, jrb.getFont() ).getStringBounds( cat.getDescription(), null ).getWidth();
       for (Case c : cases) {
            JRadioButton jrbCase = new JRadioButton();
            jrbCase.setText(c.getDescription());
            jrbCase.setToolTipText(c.getText());
            jrbCase.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( width, jrbCase.getPreferredSize().height ) );
            bgCases.add(jrbCase);
            jp.add(jrbCase);
        }
```

Comment: The above code does not work as is. It seems that with BoxLayout, setting the Size that way does not have any effect. However if you add a horizontalGlue after adding the component to the JPanel it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

This Works well for me:

```
 JPanel aPanel = new JPanel(){
      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
           Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
           Border b = this.getBorder();
           if(b == null) return d;
           if(!(b instanceof TitledBorder)) return d;
           TitledBorder tb = (TitledBorder)b;
           if(tb.getTitle() == null) return d;
           int insets = 2 * (tb.getBorderInsets(this).left + tb.getBorderInsets(this).right);
           double minWidth = this.getFontMetrics(tb.getTitleFont()).stringWidth(tb.getTitle()) + insets;
           if(d.getWidth() > minWidth) return d;
           return new Dimension((int)minWidth, d.height);
      }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" it by adding a label (BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) to the top (or bottom) of the panel. The label contains only spaces leading to the same (or greater) width of the title. (Making the label with the very same text as the title invisible does not solve it.)